# IPN listener with test form (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm new to php and have been working on my IPN page for quite some time now.

I've had to completely revert back to the basics and am following this guide. https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/

**On Stage 1:** I've copied the HTML form so I could test my IPN page. 
It states in the guide  ["*Notice that the action of the form is set to the URL you would configure for PayPal to hit for IPN. This way, you can load the form in a browser and submit it directly, which will display the result on screen including any errors that may occur. This can help to find any problems with the script and eliminate them early in the process*](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/)"

I am not getting **any** error messages at all, yet the script is not adding the values to the database, although *the query definitely works*

**Here is the form that I have copied for testing:**

```
<form action="*******************************" method="POST">
  <input name="mc_gross" type="hidden" value="500.00" />
  <input name="custom" type="hidden" value="some custom data" />
  <input name="address_status" type="hidden" value="confirmed" />
  <input name="item_number1" type="hidden" value="6" />
  <input name="item_number2" type="hidden" value="4" />
  <input name="payer_id" type="hidden" value="FW5W7ZUC3T4KL" />
  <input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="address_street" type="hidden" value="1234 Rock Road" />
  <input name="payment_date" type="hidden" value="14:55 15 Jan 07 2005 PST" />
  <input name="payment_status" type="hidden" value="Completed" />
  <input name="address_zip" type="hidden" value="12345" />
  <input name="mc_shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_handling" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="first_name" type="hidden" value="Jason" />
  <input name="last_name" type="hidden" value="Anderson" />
  <input name="mc_fee" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="address_name" type="hidden" value="Jason Anderson" />
  <input name="notify_version" type="hidden" value="1.6" />
  <input name="payer_status" type="hidden" value="verified" />
  <input name="business" type="hidden" value="paypal@emailaddress.com" />
  <input name="address_country" type="hidden" value="United States" />
  <input name="num_cart_items" type="hidden" value="2" />
  <input name="mc_handling1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_handling2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="address_city" type="hidden" value="Los Angeles" />
  <input name="verify_sign" type="hidden" value="AlUbUcinRR5pIo2KwP4xjo9OxxHMAi6.s6AES.4Z6C65yv1Ob2eNqrHm" />
  <input name="mc_shipping1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="mc_shipping2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="tax1" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="tax2" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
  <input name="txn_id" type="hidden" value="TESTER" />
  <input name="payment_type" type="hidden" value="instant" />
  <input name="last_name=Borduin" type="hidden" />
  <input name="payer_email" type="hidden" value="test@domain.com" />
  <input name="item_name1" type="hidden" value="Rubber+clog" />
  <input name="address_state" type="hidden" value="CA" />
  <input name="payment_fee" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="item_name2" type="hidden" value="Roman sandal" />
  <input name="invoice" type="hidden" value="123456" />
  <input name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="quantity1" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="receiver_id" type="hidden" value="5HRS8SCK9NSJ2" />
  <input name="quantity2" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="txn_type" type="hidden" value="web_accept" />
  <input name="mc_gross_1" type="hidden" value="0.01" />
  <input name="mc_currency" type="hidden" value="USD" />
  <input name="mc_gross_2" type="hidden" value="0.01" />
  <input name="payment_gross" type="hidden" value="0.02" />
  <input name="subscr_id" type="hidden" value="PP-1234" />
  <input name="test" type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

**Here is the IPN page code:**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sanpaypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $id = $_POST['custom'];

        if($payment_status=="Completed"){
        echo'Payment status completed';
        $txn_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");;
        if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {

                    // add txn_id to db
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                    $statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
                    if($statement->execute()){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }
                    $statement->close();
                    // update premium to 1 

                    //$update_premium = mysqli_query("UPDATE 'users' SET is_member ='1' WHERE 'id' ='".$id."'");


        }
    }

    // <---- HERE you can do your INSERT to the database

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

Comment: This code look like exactly as in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176134/paypal-record-not-inserting-to-database-php-ipn !!!

Comment: @Pavel I have used other stack overflow examples to try get my code to run yes